# Optical Frequency Divider?

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics

Is there an optical frequency divider that works to make 1064nm light from 532nm light?

The opposite of KDP crystals?

Comment: I am not aware that this is possible without using a second source. It can certainly not be done as an elementary process, since the total angular momentum would be wrong.

Comment: The second sentence is misleading - nonlinear crystals such as KDP are used both for up- and down-conversion of the frequency. Opposite of KDP is again KDP.

Comment: Are you hoping to make two photons from one? Or is a chemical (fluorescent) transition good enough for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optical parametric down conversion; this can be accomplished with a variety of non-linear crystals, such as BBO. Efficiency depends upon matching of energy and momentum conditions with the proper direction through the crystal; as you move away from the well matched case, it can be quite inefficient.  For an example of an efficient case, see [High-conversion-efficiency optical parametric chirped-pulse amplification system using spatiotemporally shaped pump pulses](https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-28-14-1245)

It is used as a source of entangled photons.

Comment: For another method, ee http://www.advr-inc.com/quantum.html

Comment: In fact, a properly tuned optical parametric oscillator does exactly what the original question asked for, and thanks to the presence of a resonator, it can be very efficient.